# file not found on unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I´m using spring boot 1.4.4 and I have a test class like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ConfigurableEnvironment.class, SecurityContextUtils.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ConfigurationControllerImplTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextUtils securityContextUtils;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
      mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new  ConfigurationControllerImpl(environment, securityContextUtils)).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getConfigField() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/v1/conf/app/prop1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

and this is my application.yml:

```
---
wo:
    ui.config.wo:
    path: "file:/conf.json"

spring:
   profiles: test
```

The application.yml is read fine ant I store the value in a String path value, the conf.json is in /src/main/resources and in /src/test/resouces

but whe I do: MAPPER.readTree(new URL(path)); I get the error: the file is not found.

I have tried: "classpath:/config.json", "file://config.json" only "config.json"

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about "classpath:config.json"?

Also I would advise to make this more configurable by providing a resource path in application.yml, which points to the resources folder, but can be changed later.

Comment: with classpath I get: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath

Comment: Don't use URL, rather use File or even better Path, but I don't think the Mapper takes Path is an input.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. The problem is that the spring context for test has not a url handler so I have modified from URL to ResourceLoader 
 and then resourceLoader.getResource(path).